# Bind tooltips to each circleMarker contained in the FeatureGroup in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm implementing a service that shows the last position of users in a Leaflet map. With CircleMarkers I would like to represent the various positions received and set a tooltips with the user's name. I add all the various positions to a FeatrueGroup object.

The positions of the users are refreshate every 10s.

```
...
this.featureGroup = L.featureGroup();
for (let user of this.users) {
  let circleMarker = L.circleMarker(user.latest_gps_point).addTo(this.featureGroup);
}

this.featureGroup.addTo(this.leafletMap);
this.realTimePositions();
```

How do I bind a tooltip to each circleMarker in FeatureGroup?

Comment: What's wrong with `circleMarker.bindTooltip("my tooltip text")`? http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip

Comment: unfortunately I had already tried but it does not work. I tried adding at the end also 'openTooltip ()' but nothing.